# SwiftUI on AppKit - Set Focus to a TextField in a popover

Tags: macos, swiftui, focus

In the AppKit example below I want the first Textfield to have the (keyboard)-focus when the popover appears.
How can I

- set the initial focus to a View and
- how can the focus order be controlled
- how can I set the focus programmaticly , e.g. as an Button Action

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showPopup = false
  @State var text = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("Hello, world!")
      .padding()
      Button("show Popup") { showPopup = true}
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .padding()
    .popover( isPresented: $showPopup,
              arrowEdge: .trailing
    ) {
      VStack{
        Text("Popup")
        TextField("enter Text",text:$text )
      }
      .padding()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I needed to do this in one of my projects myself](https://github.com/techrisdev/Snap/tree/main/Snap/Views/Search%20Bar/Text%20Field).
First, I subclassed NSViewController in which the view becomes the first responder (focused) when the view appears.

```
class FocusedTextFieldViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    var textField: NSTextField!
    
    override func loadView() {
        // Set up the text field.
        textField = NSTextField()
        
        // Set the text field's delegate
        textField.delegate = self
        
        // Set an initial text value.
        textField.stringValue = text
        
        // Set the view to the new text field.
        view = textField
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        // Make the view the first responder.
        view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view)
    }
    
    func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
        // Update the text.
        text = textField.stringValue
    }
}
```

Then, I used NSViewControllerRepresentable to display the NSViewController in SwiftUI.

```
struct FocusedTextField: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> some FocusedTextFieldViewController {
        return FocusedTextFieldViewController(text: $text)
    }
    
    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: NSViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        let textField = nsViewController.textField
        textField?.stringValue = text
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the "FocusedTextField" in SwiftUI.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var popoverIsPresented = false
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Popover") {
            // Present the popover.
            popoverIsPresented.toggle()
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $popoverIsPresented, content: {
            FocusedTextField(text: $text)
        })
    }
}
```

If you want to unfocus the text field, you could add this to the loadView function to the FocusedTextFieldViewController and use Notification Center for unfocusing the text field again.

```
override func loadView() {
    // Set up the text field.
    textField = NSTextField()
    
    // Set the text field's delegate
    textField.delegate = self
    
    // Set an initial text value.
    textField.stringValue = text
    
    // Set the view to the new text field.
    view = textField
    
    // Set up a notification for unfocusing the text field.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("UnfocusTextField"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: { _ in
        // Unfocus the text field.
        self.view.window?.resignFirstResponder()
    })
}
```

Then you can execute this whenever you want to unfocus the text field.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("UnfocusTextField"), object: nil)
```

But this will probably not work if the text field is currently active.

Comment: if I have a View with a few FocusedTextFields. How is the order of the focus defined? How can I give another FocusedTextField the focus programaticly?

Comment: FocusedTextFields is presented like "TextEditor" with 5 lines. Can I restrict it to one line (textField.maximumNumberOfLines = 1, only prevents linebreaks in the field)

Comment: If you want to focus another text field, you need to call the `view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view)` method in the NSViewController. You could use notifications like I did for resigning the first responder (which doesn't really work), and then make the view the first responder. I don't really know if by "one line" you mean the text field's size or the lines of the text field. If you want to restrict the lines, you can use `textField.usesSingleLineMode = true`. If you want to set the size, you can use the SwiftUI's frame modifier: `.frame(height: yourheight)`. 25 would be the default height.